# Suppose $X$ is obtained from $A$ by attaching $(n+1)$-cells. Then $(X,A)$ is $n$-connected.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

I'm studying the book "Algebraic Topology" by Tammo Tom Dieck: [https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/diecktop.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/diecktop.pdf)

I don't understand the proof of proposition 8.5.1:

> $\textbf{(8.5.1) Proposition.}$ Suppose $X$ is obtained from $A$ by attaching $(n+1)$-cells.
> Then $(X,A)$ is $n$-connected.

And that's the proof he gives:

> $\textit{Proof.}$ We know that $(D^{n+1},S^n)$ is $n$-connected. Now apply (6.4.2).

And this is (6.4.2):

> $\mathbf{(6.4.2) Proposition.}$ Let $Y$ be the union of open subspaces $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ with nonempty intersection $Y_0$. Suppose $(Y_2,Y_0)=0$ is $q$-connected. Then $(Y, Y_1)$ is
> $q$-connected.

However he does not give any detail about it. How can you prove proposition 8.5.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose given a pushout diagram
\begin{array}{ccc}\bigsqcup_{e\in\mathcal{E}} S^n_e &\rightarrow & \bigsqcup_{e\in\mathcal{E}} D^{n+1}_e\\
\varphi\downarrow & &\ \downarrow \\
A &\rightarrow& X.
\end{array}

Write $D^{n+1}=S^n\times I/(S^n\times\{0\})$ and consider its subspaces $D^{n+1}(+)=(S^n\times[0,3/4))/(S^n\times\{0\})$ and $D^n(-)=S^{n-1}\times(1/4,1]$. Clearly $D^{n+1}(+)$ is contractible and the inclusion $S^n=S^n\times \{0\}\subseteq D^{n+1}(-)$ is a strong deformation retraction.

Now, find copies of these subspaces in each $(n+1)$-cell of $X$ and put
$$X_1=A\cup\bigcup_{e\in\mathcal{E}} D^{n+1}_e(-),\qquad\qquad X_2=\bigcup_{e\in\mathcal{E}} D^{n+1}_e(+).$$

Then both $X_1,X_2$ are open in $X$ and $X=X_1\cup X_2$. The intersection $X_0=X_1\cap X_2$ is homeomorphic to a disjoint union $\bigsqcup_{e\in\mathcal{E}} S^n\times(1/4,3/4)$. The inclusion
$$X_0=\bigsqcup_{e\in\mathcal{E}} S^n\times(1/4,3/4)\subseteq X_2=\bigsqcup_{e\in\mathcal{E}} D^{n+1}_e(+)$$
induces an isomorphism on path components, and otherwise neither side has nontrivial homotopy groups until dimension $n$. We see that $X_0\subseteq X_2$ is $n$-connected.

According to Proposition 6.4.2, therefore, the inclusion $X_1\subseteq X$ is $n$-connected. But the deformation retract of $S^n$ in $D^{n+1}(-)$ induces on of $A$ in $X_1$. Thus the inclusion $A\subseteq X$ factors as a deformation retraction $A\subseteq X_1$ and an $n$-connected map $X_1\subseteq X$. In particular $(X,A)$ is $n$-connected.